# Is there any Comparison between .NET Workflow RuleEngine and others e.g. NxBRE?

Tags: workflow, rule-engine, nxbre

In our project, we need a rule engine component, after a short time research i found that that .NET Workflow also has it's rule engine. is there any complete comparison list between .NET Workflow Rule Engine and others, e.g. NxBRE, Drool.NET...
Thanks very much.

Comment: Just for the info: BizTalk also has a business rules engine, some say it's better than WF's. Although you can just reference its dll and use it, you still need a BizTalk license. The Drools.NET project seems to be completely abandoned.

Comment: Thanks very much for your information, BTW, can the assemblies of BizTalk (Rule Engine related) work without BizTalk run-time? Just .NET CLR ?

Comment: Yes, they can. You don't need to actually install BizTalk, just reference its rule-related dlls and use it.

Comment: Find a post talking about Biztalk & WWF : 
[Biztalk, Windows Workflow Foundation and Business Rules](http://www.edmblog.com/weblog/2005/11/biztalk_windows.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use FlexRule product as well; http://www.flexrule.com.

It is quit flexible and cost effective. It comes with Framework, Tester, Shell and Designer and supports differet engines; Procedural, Flow and Inference.

Regards
Arash

Comment: FlexRule looks good, but.... seems hard to request a trial version, i and my singapore colleague request both for twice, no response, no feed ack. So i think we drop our consideration of this 'listened good' product.

Comment: Please register yourself on the site and download and install the product. Your licence will be activate automatically during the installation process.